# Pandas df swap column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe with column which has 2 values: good and bad.

I want to know if there is a way that I can swap them. For example whenever value is good should be changed to bad or vice versa.
Is there a way to swap the values?

Edit: I want to swap values for certain indices after for loop.
Example:

```
 for i in np.arange(0,len(df)-1):
     if(df.loc[i,'othercolumnname']>=100:
      # swap the values here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html#pandas.Series.map):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': ['good', 'bad', 'bad', 'good']})
print(df)
df['x'] = df.x.map({'good': 'bad', 'bad': 'good'})
print(df)
```

```
      x           x
0  good     0   bad
1   bad  →  1  good
2   bad     2  good
3  good     3   bad
```

---

For the edited part of the question, you can combine `Series.map` and `Series.where`:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': ['good', 'bad', 'bad', 'good'], 'y': [100, 0, 100, 0]})
print(df)
df['x'] = df.x.map({'good': 'bad', 'bad': 'good'}).where(df.y >= 100, df.x)
print(df)
```

The idea is to swap the values globally (using `map`) and then revert back (using `where`) to the original `x` where the condition `df.y >= 100` is `False`.

Alternatively, you can use `DataFrame.apply`:

```py
swap = {'good': 'bad', 'bad': 'good'}
df['x'] = df.apply(lambda row: swap[row.x] if row.y >= 100 else row.x, axis=1)
```

```
      x    y           x    y
0  good  100     0   bad  100
1   bad    0  →  1   bad    0
2   bad  100     2  good  100
3  good    0     3  good    0
```

Comment: I edited question can u pls cehck it

Comment: @ElgunValiyev I have updated the answer. Please check it.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the `pandas` function `replace` that can make dict-like replacements.

```
df.replace({'YourColumnName': {'good': 'bad',  
                               'bad': 'good'}})
```

Comment: I edited question can u pls check it

Answer (score 1):

You can use `replace` to achieve this...

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ["good", "good", "bad", "bad", "good"],
                   'B': [5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
                   'C': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
                   'D': ["good", "good", "bad", "bad", "good"],})


print(df.replace({'A': {"good": "bad", "bad": "good"}}))
```

This will limit to only column `A`. If you want all columns, you can unnest the dictionary in replace. and just pass `{"good": "bad", "bad": "good"}`

Comment: I edited question can u pls check it

Answer (score 1):

Using `np.where` and @j1-lee's dataframe:

```
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': ['good', 'bad', 'bad', 'good']})
df['y'] = np.where(df['x'].eq('good'),'bad','good')
```

---

```
      x     y
0  good   bad
1   bad  good
2   bad  good
3  good   bad
```

Comment: I edited question can u pls check it

Answer (score 1):

Here's a trick that will work as expected for two unique values:

```py
df['x'].replace({k: v for k, v in zip(df['x'].unique(), df['x'].unique()[::-1])})
```

Output:

```
>>> df
      x
0  good
1   bad
2   bad
3  good

>>> df['x'] = df['x'].replace({k: v for k, v in zip(df['x'].unique(), df['x'].unique()[::-1])})
>>> df
0     bad
1    good
2    good
3     bad
```

Comment: I edited question can u pls check it

Comment: As I understand it, you want to only swap the values coming after a certain index? Or am I mistunderstanding?